# Cooling system for AMD Ryzen Threadripper PRO 5955WX

Tags: cooling

I am getting a new workstation with AMD Threadripper PRO 5955WX and an RTX A5000, custom set-up.

I have been offered the Noctua NH U14 fan cooling system, but another option would be an AIO 240mm liquid cooling system.

I have seen the reviews for Noctua and they seem really good. Would there be any reason to go with an AIO 240mm liquid cooling system? I do not plan to overclock cpu/gpu, but I do intend to run long workflows (i.e. days).

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Air coolers can be better than liquid coolers sometimes, Noctua is known to have some of the best and outperform some liquid coolers for sure. With air cooling you must be sure to have good turn-over of air both in and around the chassis. Don't stick it in a corner, in a cabinet, put stuff on the top vents, etc. Liquid coolers have a higher heat capacity because of the fluid, so they take longer to "ramp up" but once the fluid is hot all of the same challenges for air cooling just move to the radiator.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same CPU with the Noctua air cooler and triple 3090's FE and 512GB RAM in my build.  I use it for large image processing [photogrammetry] and recently started to get temperature warnings from my CPU.  Considering going to liquid but struggling to find a proven solution [out of the box].